# Unicode character issue

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode, ios6

I have a unicode character ₮ which is appearing fine in a label and UITextView but when I display it as text of a UITableView cell, it appears as a question mark.

Am I missing something here, or different iOS controls support different character sets? At backend, character is coming from an NSString and label is just showing text of selected UITableView cell:

```
self.MyLabel.text = cell.textLabel.text;
```

Please see below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: I have set `cell.textLabel.text = @"₮";` in some table view and it displays just fine.

Comment: Are you using a different font in the table cell?

Comment: @rmaddy: Thanks man, it was font issue. I was missing that difference somehow. You can give it as an answer if  you want and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be font issue. I was using a different font for the table cell as compared to other UI controls.

rmaddy's comment above helped me resolve the issue.